# Range change will ignore css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, range

I have this range box and on the right shows which value it now is, but the number is a little bit down the range bar, how to fix this?:

[image]

This how I want it:

[image]

HTML/CSS/Javascript:

```
#ranger {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:normal;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
input {
    width:246px;
    margin:2px 1px;
    padding:2px;
}

label {
    display : block;
}

label span {
    display : inline-block;
    width : 150px;
}

<input type="range" id="range" name="code" value="1" min="1" max="100" onchange="document.getElementById('ranger').innerHTML = document.getElementById('range').value;" /><span id="ranger">1</span>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/37B95/

Comment: Which browser? Chrome.. firefox, IE?..

Comment: `<span id="ranger">1</p>` probably doesn't help, try `<span id="ranger">1</span>`

Comment: Google Chrome yeah @RoryPicko92: well, now the hole number is a little bit down. See edit for full CSS.

Comment: I can't change the range slider in your question, so I can't test it thouroughly ?

Comment: @adeneo that would be an image of a range slider.

Comment: @RoryPicko92 tip solved that? Because just this short code works fine in Chrome, probably other HTML,CSS.. even JS is breaking that.

Comment: Shit, really! No wonder it won't slide, the OP needs to replace the image with an actual slider. To the point, the number always seems low to me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/36qqZ/**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/37B95/  but you cannot do something to get the number right next the range thingy?

Comment: Try with `vertical-align: top`

Comment: Ah, thank @Anto http://jsfiddle.net/37B95/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

I usually use a temporary css outline to fine tune my styles

```
selectors{
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/xcBcs/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is just to set `vertical-align: top`:

Change

```
#ranger {
    vertical-align: middle;
...
}

#ranger {
    vertical-align: top;
...
}
```